# Jmeter doesn't interpret the while condition correctly

Tags: while-loop, controller, jmeter

Jmeter's while controller doesn't seem to interpret it's condition.
I've tried the following:

```
${__javaScript(${__javaScript(parseInt(${count}) < 5)} && ${contor})}
${__javaScript(${__javaScript(${count} < 5)} && ${contor})}
${__javaScript(${contor} && ${count} < 5)}
```

I have printed all these expression in the title of a http request and the condition is clearly false BUT the while controller doesn't seem to care about it.
[image]

Comment: What is the value of contor?  what does it have?

Comment: contor is either true or false depending on http response. Even If I do not use the contor variable the problem persists.

Comment: You got this fixed? I had similar conditions and it works fine for me.

Comment: show the values of variables used.. unless count contains "s there is no need to parseInt()
check the jmeter.log output to see the errors your javascript has generated
I guess you want something like ${__javaScript(${contor} && (${count} < 5))}
Is the while controller in the same scope as the HTTP Request? Try setting the title of the while controller in the same way to see what values exist at the time of the condition test.

Comment: I've found a workaround, but didn't get it fixed. The weirdest thing:D